# Android CheckBox gets filled in with solid color when setting button attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-styles, android-checkbox

rather simple situation. I have a checkbox, I set the button attribute to my selector with two drawables for checked and unchecked. It looks proper in the editor but when I actually launch the app it gets filled in with solid color.

In the editor

[image]

And in the actual app

[image]

This is the XML

```
     <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/selected_checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_states"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:checked="false"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```

This is the checkbox_states drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_checked"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_outline" />
</selector>
```

The checked

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    >
  <path
      android:pathData="M2,1L22,1A1,1 0,0 1,23 2L23,22A1,1 0,0 1,22 23L2,23A1,1 0,0 1,1 22L1,2A1,1 0,0 1,2 1z"
      android:strokeWidth="2"
      android:fillColor="#EAC752"
      android:strokeColor="#EAC752"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M6,13L10,17L20,7"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:strokeWidth="2"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:strokeColor="#0E4DA4"
      android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
</vector>
```

And the unchecked is just a square. I don't have a style or anything of sorts that could cause this issue. But it seems that this is color secondary. So something with AppTheme could be causing this. I am just not sure what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CheckBox component inherits from a Button View so you can use the **android:background** attribute to change the checkbox state with a drawable state selector instead of **android:button**. Example is like below:

```
 <CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/selected_checkBox"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/checkbox_states"
   android:button="@null"
   app:buttonCompat="@null"
   android:checked="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There was the same problem, but I solved it.
You can use `AppCompatCheckBox` instead of `CheckBox`.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/selected_checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_states"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:checked="false"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A few features do not work while using simple checkbox or switch. Instead, when we use:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox>
```

or

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat>
```

all the features do work related to style and visuals.

[image]